# Nativescript email validation module

Tags: node.js, nativescript

I'm following this [tutorial](http://docs.nativescript.org/getting-started). At point "5.0. Using an npm module in your app" in Exercise: Use the email validator module I got an error by loading the email validator module.

> Error: Module "email-validator/index" not found.

But the module is still there and is also listed in the package.json file.

Comment: What version of NativeScript runtime are you using. You can try appending '.js' in the package.json main file, so it becomes index.js. This should be fixed in NativeScript 1.3+.

Comment: tns --version get the output 1.4.2 
What do you mean by adding the extension '.js' in the package.json main file? In the package.json file is written `"dependencies": {
    "email-validator": "^1.0.3",
    "tns-core-modules": "1.4"
  }`

Comment: Hey @StellaMaris, I'll offer a few things to try. Can you confirm that you have a `node_modules/email-validator` folder and that it contains an `index.js` file? Also, you'll want to make sure that you run a full build after you run `npm install`, to make sure the files get into the app. That is, use `tns run ios` or `tns run android` rather than `tns livesync`. Finally, I actually am currently removing the `"index"` part of this example, as it's no longer necessary per a recent release of this module https://github.com/NativeScript/docs/pull/166/files.

Comment: If you're still having issues let us know so we can help figure out what's up.

Comment: @StellaMaris I meant to add it to the `node_modules/email-validator/package.json` main file.

Comment: @TJVanToll to run a full build solved the issu, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to run a full build `tns run android` after I run `npm install email-validator --save`, to make sure the files get into the app.